# Escape slash in POST elastic search query

Tags: elasticsearch

We have an issue in Elastic Search whereby it doesn't seem to escape the slash in a query and seems to match cases even if they are exact matches.

These are the 2 cases in the database:
Case1:

```
caseReference: AB/19/001
```

Case2:

```
caseReference: AB/20/001
```

Running a query searching for AB/20/001 returns case1 and case2 when we was only expecting case2.

This is the query we are posting:

```
{"query":{
    "match":{
       "data.caseReference":{
            "query":"AB\\/20\\/001", 
            "operator":"OR",
            "fuzzy_transpositions":true,
            "lenient":false
            }
        }
     }
  }
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `AND` operator and also escape the backslash, too

```
{"query":{
    "match":{
       "data.caseReference":{
            "query":"AB\\/20\\/001", 
            "operator":"AND",
            "fuzzy_transpositions":true,
            "lenient":false
            }
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: the above search query will return both the documents, whereas OP wants to get only the second record i.e. `"data.caseReference": "AB/20/001"`

Comment: @Bhavya I was focused on the badly escaped slash

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `operator AND`

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "data.caseReference": {
        "query": "AB\\/20\\/001",
        "operator": "AND",
        "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
        "lenient": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "64773199",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.0577903,
        "_source": {
          "data.caseReference": "AB/20/001"
        }
      }
    ]
```